# How to get a ratio of male to female medal winners where a single name can show up multiple times?

Tags: postgresql

Say I have the following table:

| Name | Sex | Medal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | M | Gold |
| John | M | Silver |
| Chris | M | Bronze |
| Ana | F | Null |
| Isobel | F | Bronze |

I would like to get the ratio of Male to Female medal winners; in this case, I need to get the number 2 (John and Chris won medals, And won a medal). I don't know how to do this.

What I have is simply listing the number of distinct medal winners, grouped by gender:

```
SELECT "Sex", COUNT( DISTINCT "Name" ) AS number_of_medal_winners
FROM table
WHERE "Medal" IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY "Sex";
```

which results in

| Sex | number_of_medal_winners |
| --- | --- |
| F | 1 |
| M | 2 |

Answer (score 1):

Use a case expression to filter what is counted to build your ratio:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN sex = "M" THEN name END)/COUNT(CASE WHEN sex = 'F' THEN name END) as ratio_of_male_medal_winners_to_female
FROM yourtable
WHERE Medal IS NOT NULL
```